# Swift - Code not returning array value for outside closure

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, networking, closures

Im having a problem with my swift code. I am trying to get the values of yearsLinks array outside of the task closure but I am unable to do so as it returns an empty array and I understand this is because the code runs the print(yearsLinks) code before it can complete the closure.

I need help on what I need to do, some people suggested using async but I am unsure where and how I am supposed to implement it.

PLEASE HELP 
I want to set the array values, yearsLinks to the cells in a tableview.

Here is a snippet of my code. Appreciate the help. Thank you so much :)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var url = String()
var yearsLinks = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yearsLinks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = yearsLinks[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if let requests = URL(string: url){
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: requests)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
            } else {
                if let unwrappedData = data {
                    let wrappedData = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                              ...
              //  THESE ARE JUST CODE TO GRAB THE ARRAY THAT I WANT
              //  linkyears IS AN ARRAY OF VALUES DECLARED IN THE CLOSURE THAT I WANT TO SET TO THE yearsLinks VARIABLE DECLARED OUTSIDE.          
                        self.yearsLinks = linkyears
                              ...

                        print(self.yearsLinks) // THIS WORKS FINE AND RETURNS AN ARRAY OF VALUES THAT I WANTED.
                    }
                }
            }

        }
         // print(yearsLinks)
        // TRYING TO ACCESS THE ARRAY OF VALUES IN THE yearsLinks ARRAY ABOVE RETURNS AN EMPTY STRING??

        task.resume()

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are you actually trying to do outside the closure with the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the table view after you obtain the data inside the completion block.

```
if let unwrappedData = data {
    let wrappedData = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

              ...
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.yearsLinks = linkyears
            print(self.yearsLinks)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```